# Filtering data in many to many relationship while using pagination in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In my Laravel application I have `order` and `status` models in many to many relationship. I want to fetch the orders based on the latest status set to the pivot order_status table. I also want to filter the data according to the latest status.
This is my status table:

| id | text | color | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DRAFT |  | 2024-01-22 00:28:09 | 2024-01-22 00:28:09 |
| 2 | APPROVED | #492E87 | 2024-01-22 00:28:09 | 2024-01-22 00:28:09 |
| 3 | PRODUCTION | #FFD700 | 2024-01-22 00:28:09 | 2024-01-22 00:28:09 |
| 4 | QA | #FFA500 | 2024-01-22 00:28:09 | 2024-01-22 00:28:09 |
| 5 | READY | #2196F3 | 2024-01-22 00:28:09 | 2024-01-22 00:28:09 |

This is my order table:

| id:order_id | customer idorderable id | calls | orderable type | merchant_ref | created_by | delivery channel | delivery date | amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | ET-ORD-1002 |  | 5 | App Models Merchant |  | 36 | 3 | 2823-09-20 |
| 6 | ET-ORD-1003 |  | cmalls | 4 | App Models Merchant |  | 36 | 3 | 2758 |
| 7 | ET-ORD-1004 |  |  | 4 | App Models Merchant |  | 36 | 3 | 4888 |
| 8 | ET-ORD-1005 |  | null | 7 | App Models Merchant | 1 | 30 | 9 | 1350 |
| 10 | ET-ORD-1007 |  | nutt | 7 | App\Models\Merchant |  | 44 | 3 | 2050 |
| 11 | ET-ORD-1008 |  | coults | 8 | App\Models\Merchant | 1 | 44 | 9 | 1720 |

And this is my order_status table:

| oid | status_id | order_id | comment | created_at | updated_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 3 | 11 | null | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 |
| 7 | 3 | 12 | null | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 |
| 8 | 3 | 13 | null | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 |
| 9 | 2 | 18 | null | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 |
| 10 | 2 | 19 | null | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 |
| 11 | 2 | 20 | null | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 |
| 12 | 2 | 21 | null | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 | 2024-01-21 23:46:39 |

I want to fetch the orders with latest status based on `created_at` from the `order_status` table and also want to fetch the orders with latest status where status id lets say [1,2]

Here is my relationship in order model:

```
public function latestStatuses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Status::class)
            ->orderByPivot('created_at', 'desc')->limit(1);
    }
```

I have tried this query to fetch the latest status. But the filter is not working with the pagination.

```
$query = Order::with(['latestStatuses'])->latest('id');
$orders = $query->paginate($pageSize);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed a very prevalent scenario. And I always reach out to [subquery selects](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent#subquery-selects) to resolve this.

```php
Order::addSelect([
    'latest_status_id' => DB::table('order_status')
        ->select('status_id')->whereColumn('order_status.order_id', 'order.id')
        ->orderBy('order_status.created_at')
        ->limit(1)
    ])
    ->paginate($pageSize);
```

If you want to filter the above results by the `latest_status_id` field, you might need to use `having` instead of `where`:

```php
Order::addSelect([
    'latest_status_id' => DB::table('order_status')
        ->select('status_id')->whereColumn('order_status.order_id', 'order.id')
        ->orderBy('order_status.created_at')
        ->limit(1)
    ])
    ->having('latest_status_id', $someStatusId)
    ->paginate($pageSize);
```